# __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 9 were given

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

I defined a class as follows:

```
class Team:
    Team_name = ""
    Tournament_name = ""
    Kick = ""
    Yellow = ""
    Red = ""
    Ownership = ""
    Precision = ""
    Aerial_duels = ""
    Total_rating = ""

    def __init__(self, team, tourn, kick, yellow, red, own, prec, duels, tot):
        self.Team_name = team
        self.Tournament_name = tourn
        self.Kick = kick
        self.Yellow = yellow
        self.Red = red
        self.Ownership = own
        self.Precision = prec
        self.Aerial_duels = duels
        self.Total_rating = tot
```

And when I try to define the object like this:

```
import Team_class as TC
obj=TC.Team("test1", "test2", "test3","test4","test5","test6","test7","test8")
```

It gives me the following error: "**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 9 were given" but I don't understand what it is that I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears your `Team` class belongs to something else.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to copy this line of code: "import Team_class as TC", the class is defined in a different file

Comment: Then it is not importing that particular class or the class is being redefined in `Team_class`

Comment: It is not redefined and I tried to move them in a folder with only the two file involved. I'm using canopy but I checked "Keep directory synced to editor"